# Exclude $tf folder in Visual Studio Find and Replace

Tags: visual-studio

On occasion I have the need to do a text search across my entire workspace.  This usually consisted of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Visual Studio, pointing it at the workspace root, and pressing search.

Since migrating to TFS 2012 and being able to switch to local workspaces there is now a hidden `$tf` directory in the workspace root.  Unfortunately, this directory also gets scanned when doing a search, which is slow and unhelpful.

Is there a way to have Visual Studio ignore this directory or is there some way to specify the `$tf` folder should live elsewhere?

Rearranging project the structure so that the workspace root and the path under which I need to search are different is unfortunately not an option.