# Visual Studio - Slow launching of quick find

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Whenever I type in CTRL + F to launch the visual studio quick find it takes about 2 to 3 seconds to show.

This is really annoying and sometimes frustrating as I am used to start typing the search criteria instantly after launching the quick find and since it is still loading I generally start typing in the code by mistake...

This problem started occurring when I decided to switch to Visual Studio 2012. It did not occur on the previous versions...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Im having the same issue, but only for certain projects / solutions. I dont know if its relevant, but when my MVC project is open thats when it takes ages to open quick find. Im pretty sure it wasnt always like this though, which makes me think its an environmental issue.

Comment: I have found that one of the main reasons for visual studio slowness is due to the TFS we work with. Giving a full pc restart without connecting to TFS solves the issue temporarily until you connect to TFS again.

Comment: I have 5+ seconds, no TFS.

Comment: Got a new monster i7 PC with an SSD. No more slowness that's for sure! ;-) Consider upgrading your drives to SSD!

Comment: I had this problem in VS2015. Restarting fixed it.

Comment: I have a beast of a machine, with a Xeon E3-1545M, 64GB of RAM and an SSD. I'm running VS *2017* and incredibly this is *still* a problem! Infuriating!

Answer (score 60):

I saw [this advice on another website](http://blog.ngpixel.com/post/104460739563/how-to-fix-slow-visual-studio-tfs/), maybe it will help you.

It would appear that [other people are having the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681737/exclude-tf-folder-in-visual-studio-find-and-replace).

[Here is the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings)

---

Upon installing Visual Studio 2012, I found out that all operations related to TFS (such as adding a new file, check in/out, etc.) were incredibly slow and would freeze the application for quite some time. If this is the case for you, try this solution:

Edit the Visual Studio config file found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config
and locate the following line:

```
<system.net>
```

Right below (above settings, NOT under), insert the following line of code:

```
<defaultProxy enabled="false" />
```

Your visual studio should now be more responsive!

Comment: I was having the same problem with Visual SVN plugin for Visual Studio and this helped.

Comment: This worked for me.  Wish I could upvote this about 20 times.  Life is good again.

Comment: Worked for me - using TFS

Comment: Thank you! This has fixed it for me.

Comment: The first URL is broken

Comment: This has been the bane of my developer life for a good few years now, I just thought it was some badly written fancy ass search algorithm. Oh sweet mother brother sister father lord. This is wonderful.

Comment: Unfortunately this workaround doesn't seem to work for me in VS2013.  I see the added weirdness of having the text `soapAction="https:` show up in the search box. (I don't use TFS.)

Comment: in VS2015 I had no problem, then installed ReSharper. I added `<defaultProxy enabled="false" />` but it still take upward of 4 seconds to do **Ctrl + F** for quick find. Bummer :(

Comment: Having never had an issue with this, about a week ago I started doing some JavaScript development for the first time, and this issue cropped up. It's been a painful week, but this fixed it (on VS2015). Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: Strewth.  Even in 2017 I had the same issue and this fixed it.  This is the file to change C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE

Comment: For what it's worth, this still seems to be applicable for me on VS2015 with ReSharper.  Odd because Ctrl+F used to be responsive for me, and it just started slowing down drastically in the past week or two.  Not sure what changed in my environment.

Comment: I cant believe it, I was in pain for years and finally this little trick saved my life!

Comment: Still fixes the issue in vS2019!

Comment: Did not fix the issue for me in VS2019.
I have to restart VS every few hours else it is unusable.

Answer (score -1):

With visual studio 2017, this issue seems to have been solved. However, I stopped using the integrated TFS with visual studio. I know only use VS Pro for debugging.

I also recommend to use the new free light VS Code and do MSBuild commands via MSBuild CLI tool. It has way fewer features than VS Pro but for web development (SPA's) it's great. Do install some plugins if you choose this editor.

Comment: Nope, issue is still there, 5+ years on, in VS 2017. It's been there all along, and is still there in the latest 15.9.5 :(  I'd put money on it still not being fixed in the VS 2019 preview...